# How to modelling different types of fields and entities connection in UML

Tags: uml, class-diagram

The task:

> - Each field has place for multiple entities and have 1-10 neighbors.
>   The fields are different. Some of them are trapped and if an entity
>   steps on them they will not be able to leave. There are also
>   radioactive fields and if an entity spends too much time on them,
>   they dies. Fields can not be trapped and radioactive at the same time.
> - There are two different entities. Some of them are able to escape from trapped fields (E1) and some of them are immune for radioactivity (E2). Entities can move between neighboring tiles.

From this I have got the following class diagram (only the classes):
[image]

So I want to know how can I represent that if `E1` steps on `Radioactive` and if it stays there too long dies? Furthermore how can it handle that case when a new `E1` comes and it does not die when the first one?

First I tried with something like this, but it can not handle that event

[image]

*EDIT:*
My soloutin:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First diagram** (first version on the question)

Your generalizations if they exist are in the wrong direction, currently a *Field* is a *Trapped* and a *Radioactive* and an *Entity* is a *E1* and a *E2*, but you wanted the reverse.

Anyway there is nothing in the statement saying a field cannot be both trapped and radioactive, in that case rather than to use generalizations better to use properties.

For the *Entities* it seems there are only *E1* and *E2* so you can use generalization (in reverse direction)

**Second diagram**

Note if *Radioactive* implements a *Timer* that means someone else has to kick each *Radioactive* and only them (no other *Field*).

Concerning the time to die, if it is the same whatever the instance of *E1* and *Radioactive* that attribute can be static.

I do not understand the operation *KillEntity* because the moment an *E1* is killed depends on when each instance enter in the field so cannot be general

You can handle the delay to die for a *Field* in a *Radioactive* in that least, for instance :

[image]

- each time an *Entity* enter in a *Radioactive* the *Entity* is added in *dying* for instance initializing duration to 0
- each time an *Entity* exit in a *Radioactive* the *Entity* is removed in *dying*
- each time *tick* is called each duration is increased and when becoming *timeToDie* the corresponding Entity is removed from *dying* and the operation *die* called on it
- the operation *dies* does noting on *Entity* but on *E2* indicates the instance is killed (it is also possible to have that operation abstract on *Entity* and defined but doing nothing on *E1*)

Note you can replace the class-association by an association with a qualifier valuing the duration etc

But you can also handle the delay to die in *E2*  :

[image]

- *tick* on *Entity/E2* is applied by a *Radioactive* on its *Fields* each time it is itself ticked, *tick* does nothing on *Entity* but manages the duration on *E2* to kill the instance after the required delay (a static attribute can be shown again)
- each time an *E2* moves to a new *Field* the duration is reset to 0

---

Note your multiplicity `1..*` is wrong because a *Field* may not have *Entity*, on the opposite side the multiplicity is 1 if a dead *E2* stay in a *Radioactive* else `0..1`

Comment: I corrected the first diagrams wrong generalizations direction, also added that a field can not be both at the same time.

Comment: @Anonymous is the time to die in a radioactive field always the same for a non E2 field ?

Comment: Not specified so it can be the same yes.

Comment: @Anonymous how entities 'decide' to move (when allowed) and 'choose' in which field ? Why the precision saying a field have 1..10 neighbors ?

Comment: Because they can move between neighboring fields anytime.

Comment: @Anonymous I edited my answer to put two proposals, of course a lot of variations can be made

Comment: Created my own solution from your answer. Finally, can you show me the functions calls in a sequence diagram please?

Comment: @Anonymous what do you not understand in the description associated to each proposal ? If you created your own solution but have open points for it what about to open a new question ?